# videos playing slow and buffering

Tags: help

I have and old computer and recently went from windows xp to windows 7. Best I can do until I can afford a new computer. My problem is watching videos a 10 minute video may take 30 minutes to watch. I see the ads moving and other junk but not sure what to do to speed up this aggravating process of slow videos. Thank you for your help

Comment: Unfortunately individual tor streams have very limited bandwidth, which means that bulk non-interactive tasks like downloading large files or streaming videos can be slow. The best you can do is to try using different circuits and hope that one is faster.

Comment: *"Best I can do until I can afford a new computer."* - the **best** you can do is to use an operating system (e.g. like Linux Mint Xfce or MATE) which uses less resources, thus you hardly have to buy a new computer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to hit the onion button in the corner and click new identity this will connect you to a different circuit may take a few try's but tor by nature will be slower than a regular web browser.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I will try these and let you know results